# Add Consecutive numbers and paste in blank cell using excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have set of numbers to be added and placed in the next blank cell. In example `A1` to `A11` has to be summed in `A12`. the same for next set. I want a macro to perform this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example (as per your sample data):

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Get your current range
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Loop through each section to sum it
    For Each area In rng.Areas
        area.Offset(area.Rows.Count).Resize(1).Value = Application.Sum(Area)
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @JvdV: Very nice! I work in Excel (VBA) for years but I never  knew that the a range area can be defined in such a way...

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru. It's possible because of the gaps in the data.

Answer (score 1):

This would be incredibly easy with worksheet function `SUM`, so I'd suggest identical approach, just using it in VBA (macro code):

```
Sub SumRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    ' define range to be summed
    Set rng = Range("A1:A11")
    ' sum range in A12
    Cells(12, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
End Sub
```

Comment: It is taking only the first set value. I need the next set of number to sum and place in the next blank cell and so on

Comment: @Roguen, the idea is fine. Be thankful someone took time to help you out. Think about how you can add upon the code yourself, how you can work with this sort of code to accomplish what you need. After all, the body of your question is very marginal.

Comment: @JvdV I will take your points in action before asking new questions. Thank you all for the timely response

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Sub SumRange()


    lastrow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

    Start = 1

    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & (lastrow + 1)).Cells

    If c = "" Then

    c.Select

    ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(Start, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Row, 1)))
    Start = c.Offset(1, 0).Row


    '''''Color sum cell in green
    With Selection
  With .Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End With





    End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim arr As Variant, El As Variant
Dim i As Long, lngSum As Long

  With ActiveSheet
    arr = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).value
    For Each El In arr
        i = i + 1
        If El <> "" Then
            lngSum = lngSum + El
        Else
            .Range("A" & i).value = lngSum
            .Range("A" & i).Font.Color = vbRed ' just to easier identify the updated cell
            lngSum = 0
        End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: But @JvdV's answer is obviously the best!